# Get current child route without parameters

Tags: angular, angular-router

Let's say I have a few routes defined as:

```
'products'
'product/:id'
'product/:id/:type'
```

Used like:

```
'products'
'product/123'
'product/123/2'
```

In these examples I would like to get just the current route, without any parameters. Respectively:

```
'products'
'product'
'product'
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? This sound like an XY question.

Comment: @JBNizet The idea is to show a help menu based on the current URL. We would want to show the same menu for all children of a given route.
The reason we want to use URL is so our Admins can create these help menus for pages as they see fit.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, Yes, I've tried everything I could think of. There appears to be no such property in Router, or ActivatedRoute. I can't even get the defined child route path from the router config.

Comment: The router emits router events. One of which is NavigationEnd. It contains an ActivatedRouteSnapshot, giving access to the current URL as an array of UrlSegment. Check if its path of the first one is "products" or "product".